# Firebase Crashlytics 'Error loading your issues' and upload-symbols script error - iOS App using XCode

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I recently noticed all of my crash reports in Firebase Crashlytics were not being deobfuscated, they were all returning compiler errors and memory locations (eg `<compiler-generated> - Line 4331771636`, `EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000102afd6f4`), rather than function names and line numbers. I realised it's because Fabric has been shutdown (4th May 2020), so I began the transition to Firebase Crashlytics.

I changed my pod file and added the `Firebase/Crashlytics` pod, and followed the transition instructions located [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios).

I've put the following code in my `Run script` under `Build Phases` in Xcode:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

When I build my project I get the following error returned from `upload-symbols`:

```
Fetching upload-symbols settings...
[31merror: Could not fetch upload-symbols settings: Could not connect to the server.[0m
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

If I manually run the `upload-symbols` script in terminal, I get the same error `error: Could not fetch upload-symbols settings: Could not connect to the server.`

I also noticed that on the Crashlytics dashboard in Firebase, I had lost all my previous crash data and was receiving the message `Error loading your issues`.

How can I fix the errors and get Crashlytics working like before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to force a crash in my app using `fatalError()`. It is not obvious that this is required to finalise the registration of the new SDK with the Firebase Crashlytics backend.

After doing this, all my historical crash data is available like before, and `upload-symbols` completes successfully.

Comment: You do not have to force a crash, but you have to finalise the registration! Thanks - I have been struggling a long time after switching the firebase-project...

Comment: I actually had a slightly different error, but the fix was the same: just finalize the registration in the Firebase dashboard -> Crashlytics -> iOS section.  The error I was seeing was "Could not fetch upload-symbols settings".

Comment: @wildcat12 how ekzactly you finalised the registration ? coz I am not getting even the force a crash in my app using fatalError()

Comment: is it nesscesry to manually run the upload-symbols script in terminal?

Comment: @iMinion: nope, you don't have to run it in terminal.  Just go to the Firebase dashboard -> Crashlytics section -> choose your iOS app in the drop-down next to the "Crashlytics" title in the upper-left of the page.  At that point, there should be some instructions on the right.  I can't see those anymore, but the button you need to click says something like "Add SDK" (it's near the top).  Click that, then run your app from Xcode.  It should recognize it within 30 sec or so.

Comment: does that "Add SDK" button comes after we update to FirebaseCrashlytics

Comment: @iMinion No, you don't have to update to FirebaseCrashlytics first.  In the Firebase dashboard -> Crashlytics, it will look like this if you are having the same issue I was: https://imgur.com/a/lkvqLij   I had to "Add SDK", and then it solved my "Could not fetch upload-symbols settings" error when running/building my app in Xcode.

Comment: @wildcat12 I just tried to add a new project  from scratch and I can view the add sdk ,  But in my case its the project is already there and I am updating to FirebaseCrashlytics and removing Fabric..(Was that your case???) ,  So  I guess the the SDK is already there also , the issue is em still getting the missing DSYMS and  not much crash logs .. Also did you ticked "Run Script only when installing" where you added the script in Build phases.

Comment: @iMinion: I updated a few projects from Fabric -> FirebaseCrashlytics, and I added it fresh to one project (it never had Fabric).  I didn't tick the "Run script only when installing".  This is what I have in the Run Script section:  "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"

Comment: @wildcat12  ok ,  i think the problem is the tick which i sid on "Run Script when installing"

Comment: @iMinion if you do have that ticked it won’t upload the symbols for running directly in Xcode, only when you archive the binary

Comment: @MitchellD  it wont get  the dysm files loaded , to get crashes of users using the application in real time

Comment: @MitchellD I had worked it perfectly but today I'm getting the same error. My project is already linked and already live in-store. Suddenly today I'm getting this error